# Add environment variables in hostinger shared hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have deployed my react web application in hostinger. I made a build of my react web application and uploaded it in public_html of hostinger and my site works fine. But since I am using firebase I need to hide my firebase configuration data in environment variables. So can anyone help me in understanding how to do it and how to set up environment variables in hostinger for a react web application.

Comment: This might help: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/linux-environment-variables-how-to-read-and-set-on-a-linux-vps/

Comment: Actually this tutorial is for VPS (Virtual Private Server). Whereas mine is Shared Hosting. Hostinger customer support told me this can only be done with VPS.

Answer (score 1):

I created a `config.js` file which has the import of all variables e.g

```js
export const REACT_APP_API_HOST = process.env_REACT_APP_API_HOST ?? "*********";
```

when I am building the app i put my env variables into the string when before i push i remove the variableleaving an empty string.

You can also an automation that would create the config.js everytime you build,

that way u dont have to worry about making the mistake of pushing your envs to git,

PS: would update this once i can create the automation